# How is singing operetta and schlager connected?

Tags: voice, styles

I sometimes read or hear about people who are operetta singers. They don't sing opera (even if some did). They sing operetta.
Many of the operetta singers are also non-musical actors in film or theatre. I am sorry if I use the wrong term for this type of acting.

My thinking is that operetta is much closer to non-musical theater than opera and that operetta singers are sometimes really good at siging older forms of schlager. A good example would be Per Grundén who sang operetta in Wien, acted in movies and sang older forms of schlager.
I am aware of opera singers who sang schlager but operetta seems closer to it than opera.

Here is a link to his version of a schlager from 1929: https://open.spotify.com/track/3JRAeylL2FPfjjhPPDX4A7?si=TosZIJ6HR8KhdJXa11upvA&utm_source=copy-link

How is singing operetta and schlager connected?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_music

Comment: I don’t quite understand you question - maybe others do. Operetta is about operetta, or more completely it’s a genre of musical theater or theatrical music that has both artistic and business oriented goals. Schlager is another genre with both artistic and business goals. Neither is “just about” anything - or maybe I don’t know what you mean by “just about”. Side note: it’s not clear why you mention Per Grundén. He is not an example of a singer who did not sing opera. His stage debut was in a full length opera.

Comment: @ToddWilcox what do business oriented goals have to do with it?  Plenty of operas were written and produced to make money.

Comment: They say that schlager was influenced by operetta. Sure he sang opera but was mostly an operetta singer. Btw, his first role was in Porgy and Bess. Many opwretta singers never really had an opera career. They sang only operetta.

Comment: Are you saying that the term "light" is too informal?  What would you call it then? Isn't schlager and operetta lighter than serious operas?

Comment: @phoog The question has been edited since my comment. The question was in some ways about what operetta and schlager are. My comment is that they are genres or styles and they have the same primary goals as any genre (including opera). Those goals being some mix of artistic goals and business goals, like every other genre. Operetta seems to have been partly created in response to changing public tastes, so to neglect the desire of operetta writers and singers to make money would seem to miss part of the point of the art form.

Answer (score 1):

An operetta is one form of opera, it develops as *opéra bouffe* or *opérette bouffe* (for short one act operas) from the *opéra comique*. The field of operetta is quite wide, and includes stylistic sub genres like the Parisian operetta, the Viennese operetta, the Berlin operetta, stuff like the English Savoy operas, and even a New York operetta. These also differ in time, early Parisian operetta is quite different from late Parisian operetta, Strauß and Lehár are not exactly the same.

So similar to how you have opera singers that specialize in singing Mozart operas, certain styles of baroque operas (one who sings Händel might not sing Monteverdi!), Verdi operas, Wagner operas or whatever you do have opera singers that specialize in singing operetta or more correctly certain styles of operetta. This does not mean that they are not opera singers, and it does not even mean that they will not sing anything outside of their specialization. Per Grundén did sing opera too!

Now about Schlager: One characteristic of operetta is that it tends to be lighter the big operas both in music and plot. This made operetta very popular in the sense of *accessible to the people* and led to certain numbers becoming hugely popular, similar to a top charts hit nowadays.

So in one direction the operettas were quite close to the popular musical language and in the other direction they did influence it quite a lot (even to the point that quite a few "Jazz classics" actually came from operetta, such as *Softly as in a morning sunrise* or *Anything goes*).

But then, early Schlager takes more influences than opera and operetta, you have Varieté music, you have American swing.

Now, *Schlager* is a fuzzy term, but it usually just means a melody or number that is overwhelmingly popular. With the rise of the Gramophone music became more accessible which fostered the rise of such Schlager melodies, eventually leading to the whole world of commercial Schlager, which is probably what you have in mind. One thing you need to keep in mind about this things is that they are intended for records as main distribution medium, to be played back on Gramophones with very limited dynamic capabilities. So this style is lacking quite a vital part of it’s influences, that is articulation and dynamics.

Comment: But doesn't the microphones just make the articulation and dynamics a bit different? I mean, don't we just express them differently rather than not having them at all?

Comment: @harryjansson On a modern microphone with modern recording equipment on modern reproduction equipment yes. In the beginning of gramophone discs they did not even have microphones. Instead they had a mechanical device that cut the audio into a zinc disc. At that time you had to play as loud as possible, with singers standing right in front of the device to get something decent out of it. But even with the most modern recording equipment, replaying on a gramophone has so little dynamic potential that you cannot do much.